# Creating the view with Interface Builder, when using Navigation Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, interface-builder, uinavigationcontroller

I'm creating an UIViewController in IB. And I want to use this controller with a UINaviagationController.

The problem is when I use this view controller with the navigation one the title bar appears and all the elements on view go down. Ho can I take account of this when creating the controller in IB ?

PS: Now, I just put everything a bit higher. But I don't think it's a right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IB select the view controller view, open the inspector, select the View Attributes tab, and on Top Bar specify "Navigation Bar". This will make a Navigation Bar in the view and then you'll be able to place your subviews in the remaining content. 
In the same way you can inform IB if your view will contain the status bar, the tab bar, a prompt.
[image: IB snapshot]